# Does the Adobe Suite run on Ubuntu?

Tags: adobe

Hey I am a video guy and thought about switching to your OS. Does it support the Adobe Suite?

Thanks!

Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

No.

You can run it under wine or a Virtual Machine, but you will get better results if you use a supported OS like Windows or OS/X.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe does not support any OS except for Windows and MacOS natively. On x86 and on x86_64 you can nevertheless run many programs using a compatibility layer called WINE, which tries to substitute for the non-standard libraries shipped with Windows and which is able to read the Windows executable format. Wine Is Not an Emulator, meaning that it does not emulate a Windows PC, but simply supplies libraries that aim to have the same functionality as their proprietary Windows counterparts.

Since WINE is a reverse engineering project, afaik completely independent from Microsoft, and is still work in progress, it is by far no complete Windows API replacement, yet meanwhile many Windows programs work nearly or as good as on Windows.

Now, regarding your question, the [WINE Appdb](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26011) says that there exist some issues with [Adobe Photoshop CS 6](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607) on WINE 1.5.2. This is not up to date, since the latest WINE version is 1.6, so it might just run fine on the latest WINE, but you cannot tell without trying. For [Illustrator CS 6](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26011) there are no issues reported, so it *should* run. For After Effects there is no recent test data available, but the results for older versions are not too promising...